# разрешение аппаратного таймера

Tags: c++, windows, время

С помощью команды в терминале `powercfg -energy duration 5` узнал величину разрешение аппаратного таймера: `15,6 мс`. В моих программах требуется, чтобы эта величина равнялась `1 мс`. Как этого добиться при запуске программы?
Для программирования пользуюсь `Visual Studio 2013\2015`, язык `C++`.

**PS** Замечания к ответу от avp: вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512714/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC) я уже задавал вопрос про таймеры и многие попробовал. Поскольку работал с сетью, то отслеживал еще и через `wireshark` время пакетов отправленных с помощью таймеров. Результат оказывался плачевным.

Comment: [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx)/[QueryPerformanceFrequency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx)?..

Comment: А зачем вам менять глобальные настройки?

Comment: @VladD для RTP потока. Программа будет работать на сервере.

Comment: Ну тогда менять надо не в программе, а настройки сервера, по идее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, функции `timeBeginPeriod` и `timeEndPeriod` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx)) это то что вам нужно. С их помощью, вы как раз сможете выставить желаемую точность в 1мс.

Answer (score 3):

Не тот таймер используете. Вообще-то в системе [их несколько](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229644/time-sources-in-x86-processors), но не всегда очевидно, как ими правильно пользоваться.

Поэтому, возможно лучшим решением будет использовать функцию [gettimeofday](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html), которая выдает время с точностью до микросекунд (до какой степени им можно доверять это уже другой вопрос).

Если в VS она недоступна, то вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5197874) есть ее виндовая реализация.

Comment: Пробовал и  `gettimeofday`. Ей тоже не стоит доверять. `std::this_thread::sleep_for` теоритически может стопорить и наносекунды, но на деле - `15` - `16 мс`. Вообще я задавал похожий вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512714/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC
Ну и опускаться до ассемблера и фортрана очень не хочется.

Comment: @Dmitry, вообще-то, время это одна из самых темных вещей в ОС. Как внутри ядра, так (и тем более) в пользовательском процессе измеряемое время всегда пытается отстать. См. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=414983&seqNum=4 , http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch10lev1sec4 и пр. там. Добавьте еще возможность прерывания от таймера с выходом в sheduler во время вашего запроса времени и иллюзии отпадут. Т.е. решение на прикладном уровне всегда лежит в области синхронизации *неких средних...*, а о точных значениях лучше сразу забыть. В этом IT мире **их просто нет.**

Comment: @Dmitry,  на упомянутый [Вами вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/512714/232) я уже [отвечал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512798/232), что надо строить план событий и каждый раз пересчитывать задержку (возможно несколько уменьшая интервал ожидания от полученного из gettimeofday времени (эта величина подбирается экспериментально и в принципе может адаптивно (по мере накопления статистики промахов) меняться)) / А ассемблер (или фортран) тут никак не помогут. Причины глубже.